# Ruby validation for objects

Tags: ruby

I have a Author class and need to make some validations before initializing

```
class Author
  include Validations

  attr_accessor :name, :biography
  

  def initialize(name, biography = nil)
    validate_author

    @name = name
    @biography = biography
  end

  def to_s
    "#{name}\n#{biography}"
  end
end
```

I use module for this

```
module Validations
  def validate_author
    raise ::StandardError, 'Name is required' if name.strip.empty?
  end 
end
```

And i get this error

```
extentions/validations.rb:8:in `validate_author': undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

It's ruby application

Comment: You tagged your questions with `ruby-on-rails`. I wonder why you are implementing validations yourself and do not use [`ActiveModel::Validations`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)?

Comment: I would recommend having a look into the DRY ecosystem, which includes dry validations - https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/1.5/

Answer (score 1):

The error gives you the clue, "for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)", you can't apply the method .split to a Nil, what's happening that you are not passing anything so @name is nil by default, i don't know the rest of the code, but one think that you can do is use the "||" conditional writing something like.

```
raise ::StandardError, 'Name is required' if name.strip.empty? || name == nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Name is not yet assigned

```
class Author
  include Validations

  attr_accessor :name, :biography


  def initialize(name, biography = nil)

    @name = name
    @biography = biography
    validate_author
  end

  def to_s
    "#{name}\n#{biography}"
  end
 end
```

Or you can pass name to `validate_author(name)`

Answer (score 0):

I think because the `validate_author` runs before setting the name instance variable. So if you move `validate_author` after setting instance variables, then it should work. However `undefined method` strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` will still be raised as long name is nil.

Comment: The thing is that if i just put `raise ::StandardError, 'Name is required' if name.strip.empty? before assignment then it works too`